# Installing global package with sudo yields permissions error during postinstall routine

Tags: linux, docker, root, sudo, chown

I am trying to run this command on CircleCI:

```
 sudo npm install -g --loglevel=warn @oresoftware/r2g
```

I get this error:

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
sudo npm install -g --loglevel=warn @oresoftware/r2g
/usr/local/bin/r2g -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@oresoftware/r2g/cli/r2g.sh
/usr/local/bin/r2g_run -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@oresoftware/r2g/cli/r2g_run.sh
/usr/local/bin/r2g_copy_smoke_tester -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@oresoftware/r2g/assets/copy_smoke_tester.sh

> @oresoftware/r2g@0.0.132 postinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@oresoftware/r2g
> ./assets/postinstall.sh

mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/root’: Permission denied
could not create directory => '/root/.r2g/temp/project'...
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/root’: Permission denied
could not create oresoftware/bash dir.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @oresoftware/r2g@0.0.132 postinstall: `./assets/postinstall.sh`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @oresoftware/r2g@0.0.132 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-06-17T04_41_24_461Z-debug.log
Exited with code 1
```

This problem is not particular to CircleCI - this happens in Docker or wherever the wrong permissions are setup.

My question is - if I am the root user - where my `$HOME` is /root, why would I get a permissions error, when I run:

```
mkdir -p /root/.r2g/temp/project
```

As you can see, it failed at the very first dir - I cannot create `/root`. Even though it already exists, almost certainly, and I should be the root user, where /root is my `$HOME` dir.

Does anyone know if there is a fix for this on Linux systems? Is there some command I can run to get permissions to my own home directory as root?

I am trying to find a solution that is generic and not forceful.

I tried running this before the `npm install` command:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $HOME
```

That didn't do anything, same error.

A simple 2-line Dockerfile will yield this same exact issue:

```
FROM node:10
RUN npm install -g @oresoftware/r2g
```

and it also fails with the same error for this 3-line Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y sudo
RUN sudo npm install -g @oresoftware/r2g
```

Here is the [postinstall.sh script](https://github.com/ORESoftware/r2g/blob/master/assets/postinstall.sh).

I have [cross-posted this question](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/root-user-does-not-have-permissions-to-their-own-home-directory/23007) to the CircleCI help forum.

Comment: Can you run `mount` and see if `/root` is mounted as read-only filesystem?.

Comment: @vstm, will try that, but even with a simple Dockerfile, I get the same error, I updated the question, see the bottom

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that npm install does a `setuid` and `setgid` to nobody. So basically before it runs the postinstall script it changes the user to nobody - a user which of course has no rights to write to /root.

To prevent this you can set the [`--unsafe-perm` flag to true](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#unsafe-perm):

```
npm install --unsafe-perm=true -g @oresoftware/r2g
```

After that it worked with the docker-example.

Comment: i wonder if there is an npm config setting to set unsafe-perm to always be true... `npm config set unsafe-perm true`?

Comment: @AlexanderMills: Yes it seems to be exactly that. `npm config set unsafe-perm true` also worked on my tests.

Comment: I verified that `npm set unsafe-perm true` works, so that's good

Comment: you beat me to it by a second or two, thanks. `npm config set` and `npm set` should be the same.

Comment: this was a good solution for general Docker usage, but with CircleCI I am still getting a related error (EACCES). Will report back if I figure it out.

Comment: I added a new related question if you want some more upvotes - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50915469/simple-circleci-2-0-configuration-fails-for-global-npm-package-installation